# Is the amount of chakra extracted equal to the size of the part that is cut off from the Bijuu?

Tags: naruto

When the Eight Tails got a part of his tail cut off, Sasuke brought back the Eight Tails' body, but only about (estimate) 94% of it (due to the tail part still remaining with Killer B in it). Does that mean that they were able to extract 94% of the Eight Tails' chakra?

This also applies to Ginkaku and Kinkaku, who ate whatever was in the Nine Tails' stomach. Say, they ate (wild guess) 3% of the Nine Tails' total mass (they were in there for two weeks) did they attain 3% of the Nine Tails' total chakra amount?

I know my facts aren't spot on, I just wondered if the ratio between the amount of physical mass of Bijuu "attained", equaled the amount of total Bijuu chakra energy "attained"?

Comment: Killer-Bee lost only one tail, most of the Eight-Tails still remained inside of him, so perhaps you meant that Killer-Bee still has 94% remaining, and Sasuke captured only 6%.

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong on this one, but I think the answer is "no". Let's take a look at how chakra works in a human body.

Chakra system is much like the circulatory system of a human:

> Contained in the "chakra coils" that mainly surround and connect to each chakra-producing organ, the energy circulates throughout the body in a network called the "chakra circulatory system" (similar to the cardiovascular system). <sup>[(1)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra)</sup>

The chakra circulatory system, itself

> is enmeshed into the body and like blood vessels it touches and interacts with every single living cell and passes through every organ.<sup>[(2)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra_Pathway_System)</sup>

Much like with blood vessels, chakra vessels not equally distributed in the body. There are more of them in some places, and less of them in others, which means the flow of chakra is more intense in some body parts, and is less intense in others.

Now, we don't know much about the Tailed Beasts' body structure , but if we assume that their physical bodies work in a similar way, we can say that the amount of chakra is also different for their body parts.

Also, obviously, the Tailed Beasts can regenerate their chakra (otherwise they'd have a limited amount of it), and for some reason I doubt that the cut part of the tail is capable of regenerating chakra on it's own.

Comment: do consider that the 4th hokage only sealed a certain part of the chakra of the ninetails in naruto. meaning there is no physical body of the ninetails. Wouldnt this mean the embodiement of the ninetails is pure chakra ?