# What happens to the bodies of Bijuu's inside the Juubi?

Tags: naruto

When a human is being sucked of chakra, his body remains. This is not true in the case of Tailed Beast; their body also gets sucked.

Also, the Juubi only needs other beasts chakra and yet it takes their body as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tailed_Beasts): *The tailed beasts are living forms of chakra, sometimes referred to as "**Chakra Monsters**"* giving them immense reserves of especially strong chakra that far outmatches most shinobi

The bodies you are seeing is not actually a 'physical body'. They are just a **representation of that immense chakra** which are based on the number of their tails.

That is why, if the chakra of the tailed beasts you are talking about get sucked, that means their whole or part of their 'chakra body' get sucked.

On the other hand, on the last part, it is not necessary to get the whole chakra body of the tailed beasts to form the Jūbi. But when it does absorb only a part, anime/manga makers like Kishimoto is showing that it has already has that beasts' chakra. Please check this question for deeper explanation:

[Is the amount of chakra extracted equal to the size of the part that is cut off from the Bijuu?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/is-the-amount-of-chakra-extracted-equal-to-the-size-of-the-part-that-is-cut-off)